# Why can't I catch any Pokémon in Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've been seeing tons of Pokémon, but every time I get one in a pokéball, it seems to escape.

I tried getting more storage for pokémon, and I even tried doing curve calls and waiting for the circle to get small. This has happened with around 30 pokémon in a row.

I should mention that I was in the car going about 70 miles per hour, maybe it was because we were driving really fast, and so the pokémon was far away?

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Could you elaborate on "seems to escape"? is there some message? possibly an error one?

Comment: what kind of pokemon are we talking, here? Are you running into the standard pidgey or doduo, or are you trying to catch an abra or a jinx? What colour is the circle on the pokemon, when you attempt to cath them?

Comment: Don't play the game while you're doing 70. Seriously.

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things lol

Answer (score -1):

The same happened to me going at similar speeds. Although half of that seems to not cause the same problems.

Seems like the game just checks where you are in comparison with the place where the Pokémon appeared and if you are very far it doesn't let you capture it.

Comment: Ive noticed no problem with distance, and others have confirmed that once you go into catch mode, it shouldnt make a difference.